# Configuration file for jpackage application cannot resolve/expand variables

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-11

I have a JavaFX application. I'm generating a custom Java runtime image (that contains only the required platform modules) and then I'm creating a native installer using `jpackage` — under OpenJDK `14`.

I'm using several `java-options` settings like: `--java-options "-Dapplication.logs=~/.local/share/AppName/logs"`, but I would like to be able to use the XDG directories, like: `--java-options "-Dapplication.logs=${XDG_DATA_HOME}/AppName/logs"` because the final environment this is going to be executed have different paths, and they are resolved correctly using those across the board.

That doesn't work, the generated configuration (`.cfg`) file for the application doesn't expand the values, it just creates another directory in the user's home named `${XDG_DATA_HOME}`.

```
...

[JavaOptions]
-Dapplication.logs=${XDG_DATA_HOME}/AppName/logs
-Xmx512m
-Xss2m
```

> I've tried putting double quotes also just in case.

Can anyone shed some light on this one? I don't know what else to try. By the way, the variable(s) do exist in the environment I'm executing the file.

Comment: I use jpackage on Windows, that does allow variable expansion of certain values such as `$ROOTDIR` and `$APPDIR` in for example java option `-splash:$APPDIR/splash.jpg`, but this does not appear to work for System environment values in general.

Comment: I have little to no experience with `jpackage`...do you know if there is a way to pass those JVM system properties via the command line? The application accept those, so if I'm able to pass them while running the application it would be the same.

Comment: The generated EXE does not  appear to allow java options on its command line, they just appear as arguments in `main(String[]args)`. But you could make your JavaFX app support a named parameter such as -application.logs=XYZ and configure the logging dirs on startup not via System.getProperty